# Noobs can't copy to SD card: Can't be Read or Written Error -36

Tags: pi-2, sd-card, noobs, macos

I'm trying to install NOOBS on a formatted SD card using a Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6. I can't copy the files over from my downloaded zip of NOOBS, however. I'm following [these](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md) steps.

Here's the output of diskutil list (non-important parts omitted):

```
/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *16.0 GB    disk2
1:             Windows_FAT_32 RECOVERY                16.0 GB    disk2s1
```

I'm just selecting all the files inside the unzipped NOOBS folder, copying them, and pasting them inside RECOVERY:

[image]

Pasted in here:

[image]

I get this error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you may have a bad download. did you check the md5sum of the download?

Comment: I did not, but I downloaded it directly from the Raspberry Pi org site. I'm currently downloading the latest version of NOOBS to see if that works

Comment: Hm this is odd, now the download won't even unzip. It gives this error when I try to unzip it:
Unable to expand "NOOBS_v2_0_0.zip" into "Downloads". (Error 2 - No such file or directory)

Comment: Is the disk full? Does the downloads directory exist

Comment: Yep the directory exists and I have 13 Gi free

Comment: I still think you have a bad download. Delete the old version, redownload and check the checksum.

Comment: I just finished the download directly from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/, and it's the same error.

Comment: Did you check the checksum? Just because you download it from the Pi Foundation does not guarantee you got a good download.

Comment: Yep, just checked, it's the same.

Comment: How did you unzip? What is the size of the zip? macOS has problems with images > 4GB. (I don't use NOOBS, but this was a problem with Raspbian once the image exceeded 4GB.)

Comment: I double clicked to unzip. The size of the zip was 1.17 GB.

Comment: Maybe you got bad sectors on your hard drive, sounds like the OS cant read the source. Is your machine running OK? Very strange issue

Comment: Yeah the machine's running just fine. Could it have something to do with the formatting of the SD card? Does everything look normal in the pasted /dev/disk2 text in my post?

Comment: I have noted in the past that macOS chooses to ignore partitions named "RECOVERY". This OS uses partitions named "Recovery HD" for its restore function. If you format the SD using the recommended tool and retry it should work. I still think NOOBS is more trouble than it is worth, and suggest you may be better installing Raspbian.

Comment: @Nick not to come off as a jerk but are you using a microSD adapter? You might have accidentally moved the switch. The switch should just be for write protection. If you moved it, that could be the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Error code -36 is a problem with the hidden files (dotfiles). To fix this, open up terminal (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app). Now, in the sidebar of finder, the USB name is RECOVERY, so if it is different, replace RECOVERY with the name of the drive in the side bar. Type in the following and hit enter:

```
dot_clean /Volumes/RECOVERY
```

Try to copy the files to the USB again, if it doesn't work, make a copy of the NOOBS folder (it may corrupt it, but it may fix it also), run the previous command again, then run:

```
dot_clean /Path/To/Copy/Of/Noobs/
```

(Unrelated, whats with the ? symbol in the upper middle-left of finder.Thats not normal and normally a ? symbol indicates a missing app source in MacOS.)

Comment: Thanks I will try this. I have no idea what the ? is. That's the first time I've noticed it.